# How do I create this new data frame to implement an existing one?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame consisting of different types of shoes and the brands that made them.

```
data <- data.frame(Shoes= c(Shoe1, Shoe2, Shoe3, Shoe4, Shoe5),
                   Brand= c(Brand1, Brand2, Brand3, Brand1, Brand2))
```

I am wondering how to create a new data frame including the names of the brands and amount of shoes they made, based off of the previously defined data frame.

It would look something like this:

```
newdata <- data.frame(Brand = c(Brand1, Brand2, Brand3),
                      Amount = c(2, 2, 1))
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(data$Brand))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr way to create the 2nd data frame

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Shoes= c('Shoe1', 'Shoe2', 'Shoe3', 'Shoe4', 'Shoe5'),
                   Brand= c('Brand1', 'Brand2', 'Brand3', 'Brand1', 'Brand2'))

newdata <- data %>%
  count(Brand)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without accessing the dpylr library? @Seth

Comment: In base R you can use aggregate()
`newdata <- aggregate(data$Shoes, by=list(data$Brand), FUN=length)`